# Split the mesh on the basis of UDIM using AssImp

Tags: assimp

I have a model with single mesh which contains multiple UDIMs. I was looking for a way to split a mesh on the basis of UDIM in AssImp. I searched on the web and also in their documentation but couldnt find any way to do it. Is there any known way to do this using AssImp ? Also Can we differentiate a model that contains UDIMs ?